# NGRX store is not instantiating in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx

I am working on a new project with NGRX store. NGRX store is not instantiating. When I use redux develop tool in chrome it always show me undefined. I have attached the intial structure of my ngrx store. Please let me know what is missing. Thank you

**app.reducers.ts**

```js
import { ActionReducerMap, combineReducers } from '@ngrx/store';

import { PointReducers } from '../point/shared/store/point.reducers';
import { AppState } from './app.state';

export const appReducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
  point: combineReducers({
    closingTab: PointReducers.closingTab,
    configTab: PointReducers.configTab,
    postTab: PointReducers.postTab,
  })
};
```

**app.state.ts**

```js
import { PointMainState } from '../point/shared/store/point-main.state';

export interface AppState {
  point: PointMainState;
}
```

**store.index.ts**

```js
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';

export const StoreRootModuleIndex = [
  StoreModule.forRoot(
    {},
    {
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictStateImmutability: false,
        strictActionImmutability: false,
        strictStateSerializability: false,
        strictActionSerializability: false
      }
    }
  )
];
```

**store.reducers.ts**

```js
import { Action, ActionReducer } from '@ngrx/store';

import { AppState } from './app.state';

export function storeMetaReducers(reducer: ActionReducer<any>) {
  return function (state: AppState | undefined, action: Action) {
    const newState = reducer(state, action);
    return newState;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the reducers to the config. https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers#registering-root-state

```
export const StoreRootModuleIndex = [
  StoreModule.forRoot(
    //  add reducers here
    {},
    {
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictStateImmutability: false,
        strictActionImmutability: false,
        strictStateSerializability: false,
        strictActionSerializability: false
      }
    }
  )
];
```